# Cant pass information from child component to parent component

Tags: angular, routes, output, router-outlet

I'm trying to pass a flag from my login component to my app component so I can change a button after a user logs in.

I'm not sure if I can say this is a father-child relationship since I dont really use a child decorator on my app component, instead I use the router-outlet but I the way im doing it should work as such.

On my appComponent.html I have

```
<router-outlet (childEvent)="message=$event"></router-outlet>
    Test: {{message}}
```

On my AppComponent I have

```
public message;
```

On my loginComponent I have

```
@Output() public childEvent = new EventEmitter();
.
.
.

  loginUser(): void {
    this.loginService.loginUser(this.userNameLogin, this.userPasswordLogin).subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data.statusCode === 202) {
          .
          .
          .
          this.childEvent.emit('true');
        }
      },
      error => {
        .
        .
        .
      }
    );
  }
```

I think thats all the code that matters for this subject and I've already tried to change the code from

```
(childEvent)="message=$event"
```

to

```
(childEvent)="message($event)"
```

which also didn't work

What happens is that the {{message}} doesn't show anything and it should show true after Test:

I'm expecting have a boolean variable that goes from the child to the app so I can manipulate the information shown.

Sorry if I've made this somewhat messy but its the best way I can explain.
Thank you in advance for anyone willing to help!

Comment: Where have you assumed that `RouterOutlet` has something called `childEvent`? ;) https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

Comment: There is no parent-child relationship through a router-outlet. So you can't use Input or Output decorators.

Comment: For this case you would want to communicate through a service :) https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Yes, I do believe thats my mistake. Shouldn't be using this as a parent-child relationship. Thanks for the help everyone !

Comment: You might pass this value by services as @AJT_82 said or create same emitter for all of your "inner" components

Answer (score 0):

- first your app-component no is father than login
- second router-outlet call a router module and indicate angular where go

if you add

```
<login-componet (childEvent)="message=$event"></login-componet>
```

in app-component this works but this is bad practice